# Tickets for Level 36

Tags: candy-crush-saga

I have had two friends send me tickets, however I need one more.  A friend told me she would send me a ticket, but she hasn't received a request.  How can she send me  ticket? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If she hasn't received it, then you can always try to send the request again. I've actually tried this with one of my friends and it worked.

However, if she doesn't accept the request and you don't want to spam her again, then you can ask other friends for it. Other ways would also be using another Facebook account (not recommended because I find it boring). Actually, if you're on phone, you can do a [daily quest](http://candy-crush-saga.wikia.com/wiki/Mystery_Quests) every 24 hours and get 1 ticket. This means that you need 3 tickets total if no friends will send you passes.